# How to use SQL stored procedures with MVC Entity Framework

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

My colleague tells me that ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework Core does not support calling SQL stored procedures.  Is this true?  If not, where can I find information on how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [EF Core / EF 6.x Feature Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features) you will see that EF Core indeed does not support SQL Stored Procedures:

> Stored procedure mapping allows EF to use stored procedures to persist
>   changes to the database (FromSql already provides good support for
>   using a stored procedure to query, see Raw SQL Queries for details).

Answer (score 0):

Bosed on this roadmap in Entity framework core github page [Entity framework core roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap)

For now stored procedure calling, not support in entity framework core.

You can use [**Dapper library**](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) for now, until support this feature in EF Core.